# How to display marginal effects and predicted probabilities of logistic regression in Python

Tags: python, regression

I am running logistic regression in Python. My dependent variable (Democracy) is binary. Some of my independent vars are also binary (like MiddleClass and state_emp_now). I also have an interaction term between them.

I have this code for regression:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

Y = nondems_df["Democracy"] #setting dependent variable
X = nondems_df.drop(["Democracy"], 1) #setting independent variables
X = sm.add_constant(X.astype(float))
X = X.dropna() #removing missing values from explanatory variables
Y = Y[X.index] #removing corresponding values from dependent variable

model = sm.Logit(Y, X)
logit_model = model.fit()
print(logit_model.summary())
```

I want to do something similar to STATA command for margins middleclass##state_emp and marginsplot. Basically what it does is displays predicted probabilities for support for democracy when middle class and state_emp_now c =0 vs when they equal 1.

I am trying this:

```
margeff = probit_model.get_margeff(at={'middleclass': [0,1], 'state_emp': [0,1]})
print(margeff.summary())
```

But it does not work and gives the error: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'lower'